# Splitting field of a degree 4 irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with two real roots and two non real roots

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Let $f \in \mathbb Q[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $4$, such that two of its roots are in $\mathbb R$ and two are in $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. Let $E \subseteq \mathbb C$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Prove that, if $L = E \cap \mathbb R$, then $|E:L| = 2$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb R$ and $b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ be, respectively, the two real roots and the two non real roots of $f$.
We can write $E = \mathbb Q[a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2]$, since $E$ is the splitting field of $f$.

Since $f$ is a separable polynomial, being $f \in \mathbb Q[x]$, we have that $E|\mathbb Q$ is a Galois extension. Given that $\mathbb Q \subseteq L \subseteq E$, we have that $E|L$ is a Galois extension, too.

It must be then $|E:L|=|Gal(E|L)|$.

Beacuse of its definition, we can write $E=L[b_1, b_2]$, this means that the automorphisms of $Gal(E|L)$ depend on their effect on the set $\{b_1, b_2\}$, which generates $E$ over $L$.

In $E[x]$, we can write $f=c(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-b_1)(x-b_2)$, for some $c \in E$.

Let $\varphi \in Gal(E|L)$. We have:

- $\varphi(a_1) = a_1$ and $\varphi(a_2) = a_2$, since $a_1, a_2 \in L$
- $\varphi(b_1) = b_1$ or $\varphi(b_1) = b_2$, because it must be $f(\varphi(b_1))=0$
- $\varphi(b_2) = b_1$ or $\varphi(b_2) = b_2$, because it must be $f(\varphi(b_2))=0$

This implies that, if $\varphi_1 : E \to E$, and $\varphi_2 : E \to E$ are defined as:

- $\varphi_1(l) = l$ for $l \in L$ and $\varphi_1(b_1) = b_1, \varphi_1(b_2) = b_2$
- $\varphi_2(l) = l$ for $l \in L$ and $\varphi_2(b_1) = b_2, \varphi_2(b_2) = b_1$

We have that $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in Gal(E|L)$ and $Gal(E|L)=\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \}$.

This means that $2 = |Gal(E|L)| = |E:L|$.

I would like to know if my proof is correct, feel free to tell where I am wrong.

Comment: It looks fine for me, except you may want to justify why "$f$ is a separable polynomial". This is not assumed in the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Is the following enough to prove that $f$ is separable? Since it is irreducible, it must be in $\mathbb Q[x] \setminus \mathbb Q$. This means that its formal derivative is not $0$, so it is separable.

Comment: If I am not wrong, a polynomial $f$ is separable iff $\gcd(f,Df)=1$ where $Df$ is its formal derivative, but not the condition $Df\neq 0$. You can take the elementary approach instead: The two non-real roots must be conjugates, hence distinct. If $f$ is not separable, then $f=k(x-a)^2(x-b-ci)(x-b+ci)$ with $k\in\mathbb{Q}$, $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. However, then the coefficients in the expansion are not necessarily rational, contradicting $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: @BernardPan: If $f$ is irreducible and $Df\neq 0$, then $\gcd(f,Df)=1$ because $\deg(Df)\lt \deg(f)$. In characteristic $0$, irreducibility implies separability.

Comment: Since the two complex roots must be conjugates the Galois group contains complex conjugation. And that gives us a subgroup $H$ of order $2$. The field $L$ is the fixed field of $H$ and hence $[E:L] =2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. I totally forgot it!

Comment: Thank you for all the clarifications, my doubts were mostly about the size of $Gal(E|L)$, but it seems I did well in that regard.